# how to include <ieee80211.h> in program?

Tags: c, linux, openwrt

when I develop on openwrt , I include ieee80211.h in my program, but when I compile ,the console reminds me ieee80211.h not found.Then I set the include path like this 
`#include"/home/openwrtsdk/build_dir/build_dir/target_mips_34kc_uClibc_0.9.33.2/linux_firmware52442afee9907bc32a058f22bb3295d040677c26/carl9170fw/include/linux/ieee80211.h",`    And compile, it also doesn't work,and has following:

```
error:
/home/xuwy/openwrt/OpenWrt-SDK-15.05.1-ar71xx-nand_gcc-4.8-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2.Linux-x86_64/build_dir/target-mips_34kc_uClibc-0.9.33.2/linux-firmware-52442afee9907bc32a058f22bb3295d040677c26/carl9170fw/include/linux/ieee80211.h:897:2: error: unknown type name '__le16'   __le16 control;   

error: /home/xuwy/openwrt/OpenWrt-SDK-15.05.1-ar71xx-nand_gcc-4.8-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2.Linux-x86_64/build_dir/target-mips_34kc_uClibc-0.9.33.2/linux-firmware-52442afee9907bc32a058f22bb3295d040677c26/carl9170fw/include/linux/ieee80211.h:898:2: error: unknown type name '__le16'
  __le16 start_seq_num;
```

Now, I don't have any idea on this, any one can help?

Comment: Seriously?????? Did you look at the post after posting? Is that human readable?

Comment: Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: Sorry, the editor will hide"<",and then it shows my question incompletely

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those implicitly inferred sorta things; but the paths of include files **cannot** be absolute. The compiler has its own built-in `PATH`-like variable for compilation that gets populated by a list of default directories (eg. `/usr/include` and `/usr/local/include`) and directories that are specified by the user via the POSIX standard `-I` option. To include your header, compile your program with the additional `-I` option as you see below.

```
cc -o myprogram main.c -I "/home/openwrtsdk/build_dir/build_dir
/target_mips_34kc_uClibc_0.9.33.2
/linux_firmware52442afee9907bc32a058f22bb3295d040677c26/carl9170fw
/include/linux"
```

... and in your source file, just add:

```c
#include <ieee80211.h>
```